# mod_mono: log4net won't log anything

Tags: asp.net, apache, log4net

I have a working ASP.NET MVC application running under mod_mono. I've set up logging:

```
XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo("log4net.config"));
```

This works just fine under MonoDevelop, but with the Apache deployment, I don't see any logfiles. I even created my own appender and installed it in code to check that it wasn't a problem with my appenders being misconfigured.

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Under mod_mono, your application lives wherever you configured it, but it runs from `/`. The path you provided for the log4net config file is relative to that, not your application root.

You can get your application's root directory with `Server.Path`:

```
var configFile = Path.Combine(Server.Path("~"), "log4net.config");
XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo(configFile));
```